# Increasing the yRange by a fixed amount

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I want my legend to be inside the plot and therefore, I want to increase the yRange by a fixed amount. However, that fixed amount should be `%20 of maximum y amount`.

Some graphs I plot are percentages and some of them are just values. Hence, I cannot use the same range for all, but I need to increase the yRange so that legend won't overlap with the plot itself.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set offsets` to achieve this. Use

```
set offsets 0,0,graph 0.2,0
```

to expand the upper graph boundary by 20% of the total, automatically calculated height. This might be a bit more then 20% of the maximum y-value because gnuplot first expands to the next major tics. If you want to have exactly 20% of the maximum, you must use

```
set autoscale yfixmax
set offsets 0,0,graph 0.2,0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have Gnuplot version 4.6 then you can leverage `stats` to get the max/min of the `y` column in your data file and then use that to augment the `yrange`. Assuming your y data is in column 1 of your data file:

```
stats 'datafile' using 1
y_max_augmented = STATS_max + STATS_max * 0.2

set yrange [STATS_min:y_max_augmented] # you may use any other value in place of STATS_min
```